# Adjoint functor theorem for ordered sets: an example

Tags: logic, category-theory, proof-explanation

A have several questions regarding this example (it refers to [Proposition 6.3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEuYG.png) from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf)):

[image]

First, regarding "... whereas a least element is an empty *join*." In the proof of Proposition 6.3.7 (see the link above), to prove that $(A\implies G)$ has a least element, Leinster took the meet to be a least element. And it makes sense, since by definition, a meet of a set is (in particular) less than or equal to everything else in the set. Isn't this exactly the definition of a least element? So in the proof, the meet was used as a least element, but in Example 6.3.8 it's kind of alluded to the fact that a least element is not a meet, but a join. Or is it not claimed that a least element is not a meet in Example 6.3.8? But then why is "join" italicized?

And second, how does it follow from (6.19) [see "Proposition 6.3.7" above] that the least element of $B$ is $\land B$? I don't see this at all.

Edit: I've also realized that I don't quite understand how exactly (6.19) [see the link "Proposition 6.3.7" above] follows from [Corollary 2.3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Gck.png). If someone could explain it, that'd be great, too.

Comment: The meet has to satisfy two conditions: it must be less than or equal to every element of the set **and** it must be greater than or equal to everything which is less than or equal to every element of the set. So the meet of the empty set is the maximum element of the PO set, not the least element of the PO set. Dually for the join.

Comment: Join is italicized because what you know is about meets, so author is emphasizing that what you know and what you need are different.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Did you mean to say that the meet of the empty set is a greatest element (instead of maximum element)? Also, I'm not arguing that the meet of the empty set is a least element, rather I was saying that in the proof of Proposition 6.3.7 the author used (if I understand correctly) that the meet of $\{B\in\mathbb B: A\leq G(B)\}$ (which is not the empty set) is a least element in that set. Or did I misunderstand him?

Comment: “Greatest element” and “maximum” are equivalent here; maximum means greater than or equal to everything; same as greatest element.

Comment: That a complete ordered set has a least element can be established in several ways, including by showing that the meet of all elements of the set is a least element. But in general, the least element is the empty join, so the theorem provides an alternative way to establish the existence of a least element that does not require proving that the complete meet is in fact a least element. “Not quite trivial” does not mean “not at all trivial”.